# TextArea to Array with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to figure out how to convert html textarea into php array,

I've used a form with POST to deliver the query to the php script, 
and the php file is getting them with the following line:

```
$ids = array($_POST['ids']);
```

Needless to say that it puts everything into one line

```
Array ( [0] => line1 line2 line3 line4 )
```

I need the final results to replace this:

```
$numbers = array(
"line1",
"line2",
"line3",
"line4"
);
```

What would be the best approach to divide and re-parse it ?

Comment: I would suggest to use `preg_split()` with `#\r\n?|\n#`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Using an explode on `\n` is a proper way to get new lines. keep in mind though that on some platforms the end of line is actually send by `\r\n`, so just exploding on `\n` could leave you with extra data on the end of each line.

My suggestion would be to remove the `\r` before exploding, so you dont have to loop through the entire array to trim the result. As a last improvement, you dont know that there actually is a `$_POST['ids']`, so always check it first.

```
<?
$input = isset($_POST['ids'])?$_POST['ids']:"";

//I dont check for empty() incase your app allows a 0 as ID.
if (strlen($input)==0) {
  echo 'no input';
  exit;
}

$ids = explode("\n", str_replace("\r", "", $input));
?>
```

Answer (score 14):

I would've done the explode by Hugo like this:

```
$ids = explode(PHP_EOL, $input);
```

manual [Predefined Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

Just my two cents...

Comment: `PHP_EOL` returns the correct ending for the server. If a MAC user sends in the text to a windows server, the line endings wont match.

Answer (score 4):

Use this

```
$new_array = array_values(array_filter(explode(PHP_EOL, $input)));
```

`explode` -> convert textarea to php array (that lines split by new line)
`array_filter` -> remove empty lines from array
`array_values` -> reset keys of array

Comment: As `Hugo Delsing` said: `PHP_EOL` returns the correct ending for the server. If a MAC user sends in the text to a windows server, the line endings wont match.

Comment: Using Codeigniter, i had to first replace %0D%0A
`str_replace("%0D%0A", "\n", $input)`

Answer (score -1):

Try with [explode function](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.explode.php):

```
$ids = $_POST['ids']; // not array($_POST['ids'])
$ids = explode(" ", $ids);
```

The first parameter is the `delimiter` which could be space, new line character `\r\n`, comma, colon etc. according to your string from the textarea (it's not clear from the question whether values are separated by spaces or by new lines).

Answer (score -1):

If the textarea simply has line breaks per entry then I'd do something like:

```
$ids = nl2br($_POST['ids');
$ids = explode('<br />',$ids); //or just '<br>' depending on what nl2br uses.
```

Comment: although the `nl2br` will correctly identify all new lines, it also leaves them in it. As the manually states it inserts the `<br>` tag before the new line charactors, so you would end up with extra data on each array element which is not usefull for id's

Comment: the only issue is extra whitespace on each line if it is present - trim will sort that.